# функция waitkey в opencv возвращает неправильный символ

Tags: python, opencv

при нажатии клавиш специфичных букв получаю ответ 63. К примеру если ввожу 'Ә' то получаю 63 хотя должен получать 1240. как можно это решить?

Comment: чтобы ввести эту букву в моём окружении (убунту), я набираю Ctrl+Shift+u 4d8 получая: Ә (waitKey() возвращает соответствующие кода нажатых клавиш: 225 (shift), 117 (u), 52 (4), 100 (d), 56 (8). Для проверки: `print('\u04d8', *b'u4d8')` -> `Ә 117 52 100 56`

Answer (score 1):

waitkey возвращает код клавиши, а не символ текущей раскладки, смаппированный на эту клавишу.

В этом коде не содержится достаточно информации, чтобы точно определить символ, так что при необходимости нужно использовать дополнительные средства контроля клавиатуры.

Собственно, waitkey, как и многие опенсивишные функции работы с интерфейсом, обеспечивает лишь минимальную функциональность для простых операций.

Comment: есть стандартные раскладки с U+04D8 Unicode символом?

Comment: Я так понял, что казахская, например.